# Delete returns nothing in Psycopg2?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a fairly simple delete query in a PostgreSQL database that I'm interfacing with via `psycopg2`.

Take the following minimal example:

```
def testDelete():
    db = DbInterface()
    cur = db.conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("DELETE FROM munamelist WHERE name='something'")
    print("Results = ", cur.fetchall())
```

Basically, the [PostgreSQL documentation for `DELETE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-delete.html#AEN75303) states:

> On successful completion, a DELETE command returns a command tag of
>   the form
>
> `DELETE count`
>
> The count is the number of rows deleted. Note that the number may be
>   less than the number of rows that matched the condition when deletes
>   were suppressed by a BEFORE DELETE trigger. If count is 0, no rows
>   were deleted by the query (this is not considered an error).

However, `psycopg2` raises a error when you try to fetch the results of the query:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "autoOrganize.py", line 370, in <module>
    parseCommandLine()
  File "autoOrganize.py", line 363, in parseCommandLine
    testDelete()
  File "autoOrganize.py", line 247, in testDelete
    print("Results = ", cur.fetchall())
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: no results to fetch
```

It doesn't matter if the item exists or not, you cannot fetch the results of the query. Does `psycopg2` not return "command tags" for SQL?

<strike>If not, how can I retrieve the number of altered rows as would be returned in the console interface?</strike> Never mind, apparently `cursor.rowcount` is the number of rows modified in the last `DML`/`DQL` statement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`DELETE` without `RETURNING` doesn't return a result set. So you can't use `fetch...` calls with it, like `cursor.fetchall()`.

The affected row count is stored in `cursor.rowcount` for DML.

Comment: But it returns a result of some sort, at least within the `psql` command line client. What is the difference between a result set and a command tag? Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: @FakeName `psql` reports a command tag like `SELECT` or `INSERT 0 3` for every operation. That's different to a result set, where it prints the rows. I don't know if the difference is set out explicitly in the docs; perhaps it should be. Certainly in the psycopg2 docs.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you were after was:

```
print(cur.statusmessage)
```

When I use `INSERT`, this correctly prints `INSERT 0 3` etc.